# How to pass local variable to partial from application layout in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, partial-views, partial

I have a couple of variables that need to be called in all controllers. Displaying latest news in the layout footer.

I create them in application_controller.rb

```
@hq_news_item = NewsItem.where(:branch_code => "CORP").first
@branch_news_item = NewsItem.where(:branch_code => "MN").first
```

In my layouts/application.html.haml

```
= render :partial => "layouts/footer_news"  , :hq_news_item => @hq_news_item, :branch_news_item => @branch_news_item
```

And then in my layouts/_footer_news I style them

```
= hq_news_item.title
= hq_news_item.author.name
... etc
```

Here is the thing, no matter what I do - it keeps saying that hq_news_item is undefined in partial.

All my other partials work fine. I think it has to do with the fact that it's a layout not a view. Can't find anything meaningful in the docs.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: You don't mention where in application_controller you are setting these instance variables.

Comment: Sorry my bad , there are 2 private methods called by before filter, called get_hq_news_item & get_branch_news_item.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need to pass the variables as local variables to the partial:

```
= render :partial => "layouts/footer_news", :locals => { :hq_news_item => @hq_news_item, :branch_news_item => @branch_news_item }
```

Otherwise Rails won't really understand what you are passing as a variable to the partial and what you are passing as an argument to the render function.

Comment: Thanks. I figured out that I need to read documentation more carefully. I thought what I wrote was a new syntax for Rails 3 to send locals to partials. In all my other partials, I don't use custom names for variables, so it worked, thou not for the reason I assumed. This little peace of rails guide cleared it up: `Every partial also has a local variable with the same name as the partial (minus the underscore). You can pass an object in to this local variable via the :object option: ` Thanks for getting me to look in the right direction " :-)

Answer (score 1):

why don't you just use the member variable `@hq_news_item`?

I find I use the locals method when I have a local variable inside a view that's calling another.

This code works in rails 2.3.8

```
<% f.fields_for :member_collection do |builder| %> 

  <%= render "membrer_collection_fields", :form => builder %> 

<% end %>
```

In this case, I have a partial _member_collection_fields that has local variable form